# &* parameter in include file

Tags: parameters, include, openedge, progress-4gl

Now i'm working in one company, which make soft for banks. It uses OpenEdge and I faced with the situation, when in some procedure include file with parameters is added. After that, if it is another include file in the first one, it can be added with parameter &*. Сan anyone explain how this works?

For example:

first.i:

```
...
{second.i {*&}}
...
```

proc.p:

```
...
{first.i &f='one '
         &s='two '
} 
...
```

Comment: Are you really asking for star-ampersand or ampersan-star ???

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean &*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ampersand-star appended to the name of the second include file will pass all parameters passed to first.i to second.i as well.

```
{second.i {&*}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit tricky to find in the help documentation unless you know what you are looking for, this is the [{} Argument reference](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/Argument-reference.html), which states:

> **&argument-name**
>   The name of the argument being referred to. If you refer to an argument-name and the calling procedure does not supply it, ABL ignores {&argument-name}.
>   **If argument-name is an asterisk (*), ABL substitutes all arguments that the calling procedure passes.** It also adds quotation marks to each parameter, so you can pass the named argument list through multiple levels of include files.

Since all arguments have been passed to second.i, you can then:

```
// second.i    
message {&f} {&s}.
```